# how can I localize sharepoint custom content type description after have been created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-type

I have created some custom sharepoint content types in a sharepoint solution and I want to localize their names and descriptions. I added resources .resx files to the sharepoint "Resources" mapped folder and after deploying the solution I get "$Resources:resourceFileName,ResourceKey" instead of the localized string. I verified that the resources exist in the resources file under the sharepoint "Resources" mapped folder. What can be the cause of this problem?